# OkHttp3 response is showing error in custom adapter class in android

Tags: android

I am using OkHttp3 to fetch data from server I have custom adapter class in which I have a button in recycler view item on the click of a button I am sending request to the server and getting response.

But at the time of getting response I am getting error:

```
2020-02-14 23:23:23.222 10597-12522/com.example.aamkuconnect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: com.example.aamkuconnect, PID: 10597
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.example.aamkuconnect.AdminNewOrders
```

Below is my code:

**AdminNewOrders.class**

```
public class AdminNewOrders extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView adminSeeOrder;
ProgressBar my_prog;
AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter adapter;
List<AdminSeeNewOrderModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String URL = "https://www.example.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_new_orders);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    assert ab!= null;
    ab.setTitle("New orders");
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    my_prog = findViewById(R.id.my_prog);
    adminSeeOrder = findViewById(R.id.adminSeeOrder);
    adminSeeOrder.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adminSeeOrder.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    newOrders();

}

private void newOrders(){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("order_status","pending")
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().post(formBody).url(URL).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                        if(jsonArray.length() > 0){

                            my_prog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            for(int i = jsonArray.length()-1;i>-1;i--){

                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String str1 = jsonObject.getString("name");

                                AdminSeeNewOrderModel model = new AdminSeeNewOrderModel(str1);
                                list.add(model);

                            }

                            adapter = new AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter(list,getApplicationContext());
                            adminSeeOrder.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final IOException e) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    my_prog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){

        case android.R.id.home:

            Intent i = new Intent(AdminNewOrders.this,Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

**AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter.class**

```
public class AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<AdminSeeNewOrderModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

private static final String URL = "https://example.com";

public AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter(List<AdminSeeNewOrderModel> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.admin_see_new_order_row,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final AdminSeeNewOrderModel model = list.get(position);

     holder.adSeeName.setText(model.getName());

    holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               acceptOrders(position);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView adSeeName,adSeeDate,adSeePhone,adSeeAdr,prodName,prodCost,viewDetails,accept,cancel;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

           TextView  adSeeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adSeeName);
          Textview  accept = itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept);

    }
}

private void acceptOrders(String mobile, String product, String date, final int position){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("phone",mobile)
            .add("date",date)
            .add("product",product)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().post(formBody).url(URL).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {

            ((AdminNewOrders)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        String resp = response.body().string();

                         if(resp.equals("Updated successfully")){

                             list.remove(position);
                             notifyItemRemoved(position);
                         }


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final IOException e) {

            ((AdminNewOrders)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.aamkuconnect"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Someone please let me know how can I resolve this error.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: is this method written in the application class ?

Comment: this is the problem code:  ```((AdminNewOrders)context).runOnUiThread(new ```

What type of class is "AdminNewOrders" ?

Comment: @Lena, this method is written in a adapter class

Comment: AdminNewOrders is an android Activity in which I have recycler view

Comment: context is of type ApplicationContext ?

Comment: Its `Context context`

Comment: but are you providing it as getApplicationContext() from outside ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could tell you a bunch of things why it would happen:

1. The adapter should not be making http calls
2. The adapter should not be making ui calls (Toast.makeText...)
3. There are other ways to get back to the ui thread without invoking the runOnUiThread like

   ```
      new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable {
          override void run(){ 
             Toast.makeText...
            }
      });
   ```

But your main issue is, that the context you are providing is an application context, and is not attached to any UiThread, if you still want to do it this way, you need to pass the Activity context, and even there make sure the context is still valid.

Change this:

```
   adapter = new AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter(list,getApplicationContext());
```

to this:

```
   adapter = new AdminSeeNewOrderAdapter(list, AdminNewOrders.this);
```

and it would work.

Comment: The code i need is still missing : Adapter a = new Adapter...

Comment: Please take a look now I have added activity in which I have recycler view.

Comment: Thanks, error has been resolved thanks for giving your time :)

Comment: if this solves your problem, please accept the answer :)